# Prove that $A\subseteq B\Longleftrightarrow A\cap B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic

In set theory logic mathematics. How would i do the proof for: $A\subseteq B\Longleftrightarrow A\cap B = A$

Comment: There are two parts to the proof.  First, you suppose that $A\subset B$ and show that $A\cap B = A$.  Then, you suppose that $A\cap B = A$ and show that $A\subset B$.  Do you know how to do the two parts?  If not, are you having trouble with one part or both?

Comment: If you know a little bit of formal logic, you could confirm that $(p\rightarrow q)\iff \left((p \land q)\leftrightarrow p\right)$ is a tautology for any statements $p$ and $q$. Then replace $p$ and $q$ with $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, respectively.

Comment: Sorry I wrote down the question wrong originally. I meant ⊆ instead of ⊂.

Comment: Unless stated otherwise, $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ mean the same thing. To avoid ambiguity, $\subsetneq$ is used for strict containment. If an author wishes to reserve $\subset$ for strict containment, it should be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

First Part:

Suppose  A⊆B.  Then if for any x belonging to A, then x belongs to B.

Now suppose that x belongs to (A∩B).  So, x belongs to A, and x belongs to B also.  Thus, x belongs to B.  Since x comes as arbitrary, for any x if x belongs to (A∩B), x belongs to A also.

Suppose that x belongs to A.  Since A⊆B, x belongs to B also.  Thus, since x belongs to A, as well as B, x belongs to (A∩B).  Since x comes as arbitrary, for any x, if x belongs to A, then x belongs to (A∩B).  This paragraph and the last paragraph imply that (A∩B)=A.

Consequently, if A⊆B, then (A∩B)=A.  End of first part.

Second Part:

Suppose that (A∩B)=A.  Suppose that x belongs A.  Since (A∩B)=A, x belongs to (A∩B).  Since x belongs to (A∩B), x belongs to B also.  Note that x comes as arbitrary.  Thus, if x belongs to A, then x belongs to B.  By definition of ⊆ it follows that A⊆B.

Consequently, if (A∩B)=A, then A⊆B.  End of second part.

Both parts combine to imply that {[A⊆B]⟺[(A∩B)=A]}.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \subseteq B$, then the $\Rightarrow$ part is true, since all elements of $A$ are also elements of $B$ - proceed next by using the definition of $\cap$. If $A\cap B=A$, then all the elements of $A$ are also elements of $B$, by definition of $\cap$. Thus, $A\cap B=A\implies A\subseteq B$, i.e., $A\subseteq B\iff A\cap B=A$.

Comment: Sorry I wrote down the question wrong originally. I meant ⊆ instead of ⊂

Comment: @MarcelT. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose that $A\subseteq B$.

1. Let $x\in A \cap B \implies x\in A $
   So, $A\cap B\subseteq A$
2. Now, let $x\in A $. Since $A\subseteq B, x\in A\cap B \implies A\subseteq A\cap B$
   Since $A\subseteq A\cap B$ and $A\cap B \subseteq A, A\cap B = A$

---

Now suppose that $A\cap B = A$
Let $x \in A \implies x \in A \cap B \implies x \in B$
Since $x \in A \implies x \in B, A\subseteq B$

---

$$\therefore A\subseteq B\iff A\cap B=A$$